# bash - How to execute a later command before a former one?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I want to write a script that simulates a proccess being interrupted for some reason.

So I try to run something that kills the process
something like this:

```
ssh -f localhost sleep 7;kill pid
call_function_from_another_script_that_runs_the_process
```

hoping that the ssh command will run in the background because of "-f", and the kill commands will not be executed soon enough because of the sleep.
The problem is that sleep doesn't take effect here. the kill is being executed right away.

if I run the ssh without -f, so the second line isn't called and my process doesn't run.

please assume that the second line is as it says - running a function from another script the runs the process. I cant "put that function in a script and run it" or something that changes other things that are already written.

Any idea?

thanks.

Comment: How do you know the ID of a process before it's running?

Comment: well its not "pid" actually. its a ps command that searches for the ID by name.

Comment: No.  The idea is to run something that will kill the process when it will run (I take 10 seconds just to be sure). The process that I want to kill is run by a call to a function from another script. thats why I can't run the process in the background and then kill it, or Can I?

Comment: Sure you can, but I suspect there's a race condition here. Why don't you wait on *an event* rather than an arbitrary period of time?

Comment: I'm not a bash scripting expert, as you can see. I guess I could take the command that finds the process by name and put it in a loop so I would know the exact time when the process is run and kill it then. In this case its not required. Do you see any other way I could do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to use `ssh` to run something in the background. Use this:

```
(
    sleep 7
    kill pid
) &
call_function_from_another_script_that_runs_the_process
```

Notice the "&" which puts the whole subshell in the background. Inside the subshell, first a `sleep` is run, then a `kill`.

Incidentally, the reason why the `kill` command in your example takes effect right away is because that line of the script has two commands: "`ssh -f localhost sleep 7`" and "`kill pid`", not one command ("`sleep 7;kill pid`") inside an SSH session.

Comment: Thanks for the both insights!

Comment: This is great, but how do you know the PID?

Answer (score 1):

Try quoting your ssh command as shown below. If you don't quote, the semicolon marks the end of the `ssh` command and so the second `kill` commmand is executed immediately after the ssh command has been put in the background.

```
ssh -f localhost "sleep 7;kill pid"
call_function_from_another_script_that_runs_the_process
```

Comment: Is `ssh localhost` *really* necessary?

Comment: no, it's not. I'm just explaining what is wrong with the OP's command and how he can fix it, not suggesting a brand new alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Use `&` to run your process in the background.

```
some_long_running_process &
pid=$!
sleep 7
kill ${pid}
```

Done.